# RichTextBox caret position when inserting rtf string

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf, caret

I am trying to insert [rtf](/questions/tagged/rtf) string into a `RichTextBox`. This is the `KeyUp` event form `RichTextBox`:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string st = richTextBox1.Rtf;
    st=st.Insert(750, "void");
    richTextBox1.Rtf = st;
}
```

The problem is that, after each update, the caret goes before the inserted text and I want to keep it at the end. I noticed that this is happening only when I modify the length of `st`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't fathom how your code is supposed to work for the end user.  How would you even know that at index 750 you have text versus an [rtf](/questions/tagged/rtf) control character?

The quick solution is to just set the caret position to the end yourself:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string st = richTextBox1.Rtf;
    st=st.Insert(750, "void");
    richTextBox1.Rtf = st;
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength;
}
```

Of course, if you are trying to put the caret at the position where void is inserted, that wouldn't work with your [rtf](/questions/tagged/rtf) property, since the [rtf](/questions/tagged/rtf) and text properties are different things.

If trying to insert text in the text property, then it would look something like this:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string st = richTextBox1.Text;
    st=st.Insert(750, "void");
    richTextBox1.Text = st;
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 750 + 4;
}
```